# Changing the value of an attribute dynamically in cpp

Tags: c++, c

I have a struct :

```
struct Person{
  int scoreone;
  int scoretwo;
  int scoretotal;
}
main(){
  Person a;
  a.scoreone=3;
  a.scoretwo=5;
  //and later 
  a.scoreone=10;
}
```

I want the scoretotal to be updated when scoreone and scoretwo are chnaged without using any function.
Thanks

Comment: More code please ? & What's your question ?

Comment: Please decide for a language. Is this C or C++? I suggest C++.

Comment: As well as being unclear as to which language you are coding in, your `main` is not right. Use a proper declaration for `main`.

Comment: how about macro if you just don't like function?

Comment: I have edited the title and added c++

Comment: `without using any function` Tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done--to change a value automatically, you need to run some code, and (in either C or C++) code is always in a function.

The rest of this answer assumes the use of C++, and won't work in C at all.

You can, however, keep the fact that it's a function from being externally visible, which (I'd guess) is what you care about:

```
struct Person { 
    int scoreone;
    int scoretwo;

    class total  {
        int *a, *b;
    public:
        total(int *a, int *b) : a(a), b(b) {}
        operator int() { return *a + *b; }
    } scoretotal;

    Person() : scoretotal(&scoreone, &scoretwo) {}
};
```

This does have a (usually minor) side effect. It depends upon an implicit conversion from `Person::total` to `int` to do its job. That can lead to unexpected results in a couple of situations. One would be if you're trying to use `some_person.scoretotal` in a situation where you expect an implicit conversion from `int` to some other type. You're already using an implicit conversion from `Person::total` to `int`, and the compiler will only use one user-defined conversion implicitly, that would fail. In the other direction, if you were to use `auto x = some_person.scoretotal;`, `x` would be a `Person::total` rather than an `int`, because `auto` would deduce the actual type without the implicit conversion happening.

As long as you do relatively obvious things like:

```
Person some_person;

some_person.scoreone = 1;
some_person.scoretwo = 2;

int total = some_person.scoretotal;

std::cout << "Total score: " << some_person.scoretotal;
```

...you'll get `scoretotal` tracking the total of `scoreone` and `scoretwo` without making it obvious that a function has to be invoked to do that.

Answer (score 6):

That can't be done in C++. The C++ way to handle this is to convert scoretotal to a *method*

```
struct Person{
    int scoreone;
    int scoretwo;
    int scoretotal() { return scoreone + scoretwo; }
};
```

Now instead of saying `person.scoretotal` you say `person.scoretotal()` and the score total will be recalculated each time.

Comment: why my compiler complain 'struct Person' has no member named 'scoretotal' when I want to print it?

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of the language that you are using, the fundamental problem is in the design of your `struct`. There are only two independent data values in this structure. But you are storing three. That is the mistake.

What you need to to is store just the two primary values, `scoreone` and `scoretwo`. Those are the `data`. The other value is a derived value defined by the relationship that the total is equal to the sum `scoreone + scoretwo`.

So you should remove the data member `scoretotal` and replace it with a function if you are coding in C, or a member function if you are coding in C++. In C the code might look like this:

```
struct Person{
  int scoreone;
  int scoretwo;
};

int scoretotal(const struct Person person)
{
    return person.scoreone + person.scoretwo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare struct Person the way john did in his answer you should not get an error when calling the scoretotal function. Remember to include the parentheses, saying "person.scoretotal" won't work, you have to write "person.scoretotal()" because you're calling a function in the Person-struct, not asking for a member.